# If you SELECT * FROM table1,table2, why is the behavior that it shows every permutation?

Tags: mysql

Why is the behavior of `SELECT * FROM pokemon,football_team` that it results in every permutation?

```
pokemon_name|team_name
______________________
Pikachu     | Denver Broncos
Pikachu     | Cincinnati Bengals
Pikachu     | Dallas Cowboys
Bulbasaur   | Denver Broncos
Bulbasaur   | Cincinnati Bengals
Bulbasaur   | Dallas Cowboys
Squirtle    | Denver Broncos
Squirtle    | Cincinnati Bengals
Squirtle    | Dallas Cowboys
```

I would think that the default behavior would be to look like this:

```
pokemon_name|team_name
______________________
Pikachu     | NULL
Bulbasaur   | NULL
Squirtle    | NULL
NULL        | Denver Broncos
NULL        | Cincinnati Bengals
NULL        | Dallas Cowboys
```

Comment: That was an old standart. What you think is possible with union statement.

Comment: it is like doing a cross-join. It be doin' what you told it to do

Comment: ***Why is the behavior... ?*** That's just SQL standard.  without join criteria, you obtain a cartesean product records in 1st table * records in second table.  The nature of a Join in SQL is every record to every record unless limits are imposed.  Is you question really "why would engineers develop an RDBMS  to work this way?

Comment: @xQbert yes---"why would engineers develop an RDBMS to work this way?" is what I am getting at. I didn't realize that "the nature of a Join in SQL is every record to every record unless limits are imposed." which is why I was confused.

Comment: @NickManning  If I run a manufacturing company and I sell widgets of multiple sizes of any color, then a production run could be the combination of any widget with any color (Cartesian) in genetics, the pairing for eye color could be based on any combination of dominant and recessive genes from the parents: as a result, a Cartesian defines the possibilities.  These are two real life reasons why a Cartesian would be helpful.  RDBMS is based on set theory, which contain Cartesian.  As to why it's default behavior, you start with the largest set (cartesian) and take away, it's a logical approach.

Answer (score 1):

By default your query is applying normal (inner) join between two tables (in your query its Cartesian product where each row of first table is joined against each row of second table.

For your expected output you need to use the full outer join as below

```
-- 
select * from pokemon full outer join football_team /* add your joining condtion here using ON clause */;
```

**Note:** FULL OUTER JOIN clause is not implemented in MySQL

For MySQL the same behaviour can be achieved using LEFT, RIGHT OUTER JOIN and UNION ALL (eg. below )

```
SELECT TableA.*, TableB.* 
FROM 
TableA LEFT OUTER JOIN TableB
ON TableA.id= TableB.id

UNION ALL

SELECT TableA.*, TableB.*
FROM 
TableA RIGHT OUTER JOIN TableB
ON TableA.id= TableB.id
```

Comment: @Drew, yes your are right, I modifed (cross to cartesian) it in the answer

Comment: That's not a full outer join

Comment: Good info---but my question isn't about how to get a full outer join in mysql. My question is as xQbert helped me pinpoint: Why would engineers develop an RDBMS to work this way (i.e. default join is cartesian product)? I'm starting to grasp it though I think. Joins and On's are meant to filter the results of the cartesian product.

Answer (score 0):

That would be...

```
SELECT pokemon_name
     , NULL team_name
  FROM pokemon
 UNION 
   ALL
SELECT NULL
     , team_name
  FROM football_team
```

|

Answer (score 0):

People misunderstood my question---they thought I was trying to produce a full outer join. This was just what I expected the default behavior of MySQL to be before joins were introduced into the equation. To my surprise, the default behavior is a cartesian product. I wanted to know why returning a cartesian product is useful.

@xQbert helped me reprhase my question: Why would engineers develop an RDBMS to return a cartesian product by default when selecting from many tables with no joins?

Now I understand better---this allows "joins" and "ons" to act as filters to filter the results of a SELECT statement.

Comment: No. Your query has a join. Ignoring historical accuracy for a moment, 'comma' (',') is (in effect) shorthand for 'join'. And 'comma ... WHERE...' is shorthand for 'JOIN... ON...'. If you never use a comma join again, you won't go far wrong.